# Lendo valores de uma string

Tags: c++, vector

Comecei a estudar agora c++ e não compreendo bem ainda. Preciso obter diversas informações em cada linha de um vetor de string, portanto pensei em utilizar o `sscanf`, no entanto estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

> ```
> In function ‘int main()’:
> error: cannot convert ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >::value_type {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int sscanf(const char*, const char*, ...)’
>    sscanf(inputs[0], "%d %d", &n, &m);
>                                     ^
> error: cannot convert ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >::value_type {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int sscanf(const char*, const char*, ...)’
>    sscanf(inputs[1], "%d %d %d", &x, &y, &z);
> ```

O meu código esta assim:

```
int n, m, x, y, z;
vector<string> inputs;
string read;
while (1){
    getline(cin, read);
    if(!read.compare("0 0"))
        break;
    inputs.push_back(read);
}
sscanf(inputs[0], "%d %d", &n, &m);
sscanf(inputs[1], "%d %d %d", &x, &y, &z);
```

Comment: tenta usar inputs[x].c_str()

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro indica-lhe que `sscanf` tem que receber um `const char*` como primeiro parâmetro e não uma `string` como está a passar.

Veja a assinatura da função [`sscanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/):

```
int sscanf ( const char * s, const char * format, ...);
//-------------^
```

Para resolver pode obter o ponteiro para o array de carateres da `string` através da função [`c_str`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/):

```
sscanf(inputs[0].c_str(), "%d %d", &n, &m);
//---------------^aqui
sscanf(inputs[1].c_str(), "%d %d %d", &x, &y, &z);
```

[Veja este exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/rAbdmY)